# React Native on windows 10 : npm install from mac project creates command not found issue

Tags: react-native, npm

I am facing weird issue while try to install the react native node module using 'npm install' command for a project running fine on mac machine but when I run it on windows 10; it end up with error message stating that command failed as '.' (dot) command not recognise.

Here is debug fail snippet. I would highly appreciate anyone to guide me fix this problem. Thank you very much.

```
2092 info run react-native-router-flux@4.0.6 postinstall node_modules/react-native-router-flux ./node_modules/.bin/opencollective postinstall
2093 info run react-native-router-flux@4.0.6 postinstall { code: 1, signal: null }
2094 info run native-base@2.12.1 postinstall { code: 0, signal: null }
2095 timing build:run:postinstall:node_modules/native-base Completed in 146ms
2096 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 4215ms
2097 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
2098 timing command:install Completed in 37508ms
2099 verbose stack Error: command failed
2099 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NAV\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
2099 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
2099 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
2099 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
2100 verbose pkgid react-native-router-flux@4.0.6
2101 verbose cwd E:\BFC-Caterer\bfc-caterer
2102 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
2103 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\NAV\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i"
2104 verbose node v16.10.0
2105 verbose npm  v7.24.1
2106 error code 1
2107 error path E:\BFC-Caterer\bfc-caterer\node_modules\react-native-router-flux
2108 error command failed
2109 error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c ./node_modules/.bin/opencollective postinstall
2110 error '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
2110 error operable program or batch file.
2111 verbose exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly have you installed node on your Windows system? If you're not sure go into the cmd and run:

```
node -v
```

It should give you a version, if not then go to https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and download Node.js and install it, then go into the cmd again and run the above mentioned command.

The '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command error usually has something to do when the computer can't find the program that you are asking to launch. Go to C:\Windows\system32\ to see if the program "cmd.exe" is actually there, if it is there then go to your environment variables and look if there is a path for: **C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c ./node_modules/.bin/opencollective**. If not add it and try to start your project again.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, highly appreciate it. I do have node installed as other proejcts works fine. Interestingly I found out that this issue is fixed when I use older version of node for the particular project. Its solved my problem but don't understand the cause of the problem.